Tkinter Limits Frame vs Canvas
Creating an ImageGallery I used a scrolled Frame for thumbnails.
This scrolled Frame gets filled with ~300 labels that hold the images.
The Frame however seems to be limited at around max(shortInt), the canvas seems not to be that limited.
From what I gathered from similar questions is that there is a limit of +/-32767 coordinate points inside the canvas. It does however look like the canvas (orange area) is capable of more than the frame.

Code for the scrolled Frame:

from sys import hexversion
if hexversion < 0x03000000:
    # pylint: disable=import-error
    # if we are in 0x02whaterver that works
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

class ScrolledFrame(ttk.Frame, object):
    """
    Scrolled Frame, can use an horizontal scrollbar or none.

    Scrolling via mousewheel is also supported.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        # *args and **kwargs are used implicitly
        scrollbars = kwargs.pop("scrollbars", [])

        if hexversion < 0x03000000:
            super(ScrolledFrame, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.hsb = None

        if "h" in scrollbars:
            self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal")
            self.hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

        # The Canvas which supports the Scrollbar Interface, layout to the left
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="orange")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

        # Bind the Scrollbar to the self.canvas Scrollbar Interface
        if "h" in scrollbars:
            self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
            self.hsb.configure(command=self.canvas.xview)

        # The Frame to be scrolled, layout into the canvas
        # All widgets to be scrolled have to use this Frame as parent
        self.scrolled_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas, style="Scrolled.TFrame")
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.scrolled_frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.scrolled_frame")

        if self.hsb:
            self.scrolled_frame.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', self.__on_hscroll)

        # Configures the scrollregion of the Canvas dynamically
        self.scrolled_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)

        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.configure("Scrolled.TFrame", background="red")
    #end __init__

    def __on_hscroll(self, event):
        #print(f"{event} on {self}")
        self.canvas.xview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), 'units')
    #end __on_hscroll

    def on_configure(self, event):
        """Set the scroll region to encompass the scrolled frame"""
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        for child in self.scrolled_frame.winfo_children():
            # print(child)
            if self.hsb:
                child.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', self.__on_hscroll)
    #end on_configure
#end class ScrolledFrame

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.title("Test 34 - Show Frame Limits")

x = 0
images=[]
while x < limit:
    w = 60
    h = 80
    images.append(
        ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', (w, h), color = (255,0,255)))
    )
    x += w

view = ScrolledFrame(root, scrollbars=["h"])
view.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

for image in images:
    ttk.Label(view.scrolled_frame, image=image).grid(row=0, column=images.index(image), sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

root.mainloop()



Is there a way to show more than the current limits of the frame?
Do I understand it correctly that Frame and Canvas have different limits?
Is there documentation for me to understand these limits?


It is not a good design to load too many images at the same time.  Use paging design instead.

I do agree that it might not be the best design idea.
The question however was why two widgets seem to behave differently and where I can find it inside the tcl/tk documentation because I could not seem to find anything related to limits.
